# User-defined awk function not working

Tags: awk

I have solved Project Euler Problem 3, but the thing is that I am not able to create the function in awk.

I have tried this working code (**without** function):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    n=600851475143;
    x=2; # minimal prime
    while ( x<n ) {
        if ( (n%x) == 0 ) {
            n = n/x
            print n
        } else { # if n not divisible then increment x+1
            x++
        }
    }
}
```

Not working **with** the function

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
# What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

function get.PrimeFactor(n) {
    x=2; # minimal prime
    while ( x<n ) {
        if ( (n%x) == 0 ) {
            n = n/x
            print n
        }
        else { # if n not divisible then increment x+1
            x++
        }
    }

BEGIN {
    n = $1 # input number by user
    get.PrimeFactor(n)
}
```

I have tried several ways to work with the function but no luck.

Can anyone highlight what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the dot.  Valid awk function names consist of a sequence of letters, digits and underscore, and don't begin with  digit.

Comment: hmm.. good to know... let me check with that.. thanks..

Comment: now it is working.. but another issue why it not accepting `$1` input value as command argument

Comment: I'm trying  `awk -f script value` and it is not taking `value` as `$1`

Comment: thanks tink, I did it using `ARGV[1]`

Comment: To get shell variables into awk you need to do something like this:  **awk -vinput=$1 '{ print input }' **

Comment: I don't want to user should type like this.. seems `ARGV[1]` is fine

Comment: @tink, you forgot quotes around `$1` and beware that with that syntax, `awk` expands ANSI C escape sequences (`\n`, `\b`...) in the argument provided. Using `ENVIRON` or `ARGV` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Thx @StephaneChazelas ... always something else to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Working AWK Script with function.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
# What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

function get_PrimeFactor(n) {
    x=2; # minimal prime
    while ( x<n ) {
        if ( (n%x) == 0 ) {
            n = n/x
        }
        else { # if n not divisible then increment x+1
            x++
        }
    }
    return n
}

BEGIN {
    n = ARGV[1] # input number by user
    print get_PrimeFactor(n)
}
```